# C# Get Proxy IP like PHP

Tags: c#, php, ip

Got a Game Emulator built in C#.

When a user logs into it, it records their IP address for banning etc...

We are behind a reverse proxy, so of course all connections coming into the emulator are the IP of the proxy.

But on our PHP page for register, we used this code...

```
function getRealIpAddr() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

And that manages to return the proper IP of the client through our reverse proxy.

This is how I am at the moment getting the IP of the client in C#...

```
public string RemoteAddress
{
    get
    {
        return ((mSocket != null && mSocket.Connected ?
            mSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':')[0] : string.Empty));
    }
}
```

To give you some context, `mSocket` is the Socket of the client connecting

Is there a function for C# that can do the same? All the answers I have seen direct me to ASP but I don't need that!

Comment: The PHP example is for a HTTP reverse proxy that can pass X-Forwarded-For or Client-IP.
Is the C# program also behind the same reverse proxy, and does it talk HTTP?

Comment: What protocol is your game using?

Comment: @C.M. TCP and I have figured out a way to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to when the user logs into it using PHP, it will now set their IP instead of the emulator doing it when they connect to that!

Cheers
Richard :)